# Istio upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination for mTLS mode

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, devops, istio, istio-sidecar

I am new to istio  and i am trying to enable the STRICT mode of mTLS at the namespace level i.e

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: prod
  namespace: prod
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

Everything seems to be working fine when the mode was set to PERMISSIVE.

Let me give you a flow of my api.

istio-gateway(tls terminated) -> virtual-service-> myservice-gateway(spring cloud-gateway svc1) -> another-service-svc2 (through load balancing).
So when i hit some endpoint in the myservice-gateway(svc1), it returns succesfully but when it calls other services i get *upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination*. This happens when i call other services from one service.

When i check the logs of my  svc2 istio-proxy i get:

```
[2022-10-31T00:10:46.935Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46738 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:46.966Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46742 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:47.001Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46746 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:51.746Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46864 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:51.782Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46868 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:51.846Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46872 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:52.048Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46876 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:52.067Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46882 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:52.113Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46888 - -
[2022-10-31T00:10:52.308Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 172.17.0.10:8084 172.17.0.8:46898 - -
```

The ingress gateway log shows:

```
[2022-10-31T00:13:08.800Z] "GET /transaction/actuator HTTP/2" 503 URX via_upstream - "-" 0 95 110 108 "172.17.0.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.36" "90b95e7a-2a34-94f3-b804-a1922d529d82" "api-gateway.com" "172.17.0.8:8765" outbound|8765||api-gateway.prod.svc.cluster.local 172.17.0.22:51514 172.17.0.22:8443 172.17.0.1:31955 api-gateway.com -
```

Below are my kubernetes file:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
  namespace: prod
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: secret-tls
      mode: SIMPLE
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
  namespace: prod
spec:
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  hosts:
  - api-gateway.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api-gateway.prod.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8765
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: rule
  namespace: prod
spec:
  host: '*.local'
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

my svc1 file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: api-gateway
    namespace: prod
    labels:
        app: api-gateway
        version: v1
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: api-gateway
            version: v1
    template:
        metadata:                   
            labels:
                app: api-gateway
                version: v1
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: api-gateway
          containers:
          - name: api-gateway
            image: sunday/api-gateway
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8765
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /actuator/health/liveness
                port: 8765
              initialDelaySeconds: 300
              periodSeconds: 5
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /actuator/health/readiness
                port: 8765
              initialDelaySeconds: 300 
              periodSeconds: 10              
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: api-gateway
    service: api-gateway
  name: api-gateway
  namespace: prod
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8765
    targetPort: 8765
  selector:
    app: api-gateway 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
  namespace: prod
  labels:
    account: api-gateway
```

my svc 2

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: transaction
    namespace: prod    
    labels:
        app: transaction
        version: v1
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: transaction
            version: v1
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: transaction
                version: v1
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: transaction        
          containers:
          - name: transaction
            image: sunday/transaction
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8084            
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /actuator/health/liveness
                port: 8084
              initialDelaySeconds: 300
              periodSeconds: 5
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /actuator/health/readiness
                port: 8084
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: transaction
    service: transaction
  name: transaction
  namespace: prod
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8084
    targetPort: 8084
  selector:
    app: transaction
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: prod
  name: transaction
  labels:
    account: transaction
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: transaction
  namespace: prod
spec:
  hosts:
  - transaction.prod.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8084
        host: transaction.prod.svc.cluster.local
```

istioctl proxy-config cluster -n istio-system   istio-ingressgateway-66d5c58595-7n9r5

```
SERVICE FQDN                                                           PORT      SUBSET     DIRECTION     TYPE           DESTINATION RULE
BlackHoleCluster                                                       -         -          -             STATIC
agent                                                                  -         -          -             STATIC
api-gateway.prod.svc.cluster.local                                     8765      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
cloud-config.prod.svc.cluster.local                                    8888      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
customer.prod.svc.cluster.local                                        8081      -          outbound      EDS            customer.prod
dashboard-metrics-scraper.kubernetes-dashboard.svc.cluster.local       8000      -          outbound      EDS
docker-mysql.prod.svc.cluster.local                                    3306      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
employee.prod.svc.cluster.local                                        8082      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
eureka.prod.svc.cluster.local                                          8761      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
github.com                                                             443       -          outbound      STRICT_DNS     transaction.prod
ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local     443       -          outbound      EDS
ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local               80        -          outbound      EDS
ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local               443       -          outbound      EDS
istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                     80        -          outbound      EDS
istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                     443       -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    80        -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    443       -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    3306      -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    8765      -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    15021     -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    15443     -          outbound      EDS
istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                    31400     -          outbound      EDS
istio-operator.istio-operator.svc.cluster.local                        8383      -          outbound      EDS
istiod.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                  443       -          outbound      EDS
istiod.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                  15010     -          outbound      EDS
istiod.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                  15012     -          outbound      EDS
istiod.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                  15014     -          outbound      EDS
keycloak-headless.prod.svc.cluster.local                               443       -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
keycloak-headless.prod.svc.cluster.local                               8080      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
keycloak.prod.svc.cluster.local                                        443       -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
keycloak.prod.svc.cluster.local                                        8080      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                   9090      -          outbound      EDS
kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                   20001     -          outbound      EDS
kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local                                 53        -          outbound      EDS
kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local                                 9153      -          outbound      EDS
kubernetes-dashboard.kubernetes-dashboard.svc.cluster.local            80        -          outbound      EDS
kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local                                   443       -          outbound      EDS
loan.prod.svc.cluster.local                                            8083      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
metrics-server.kube-system.svc.cluster.local                           443       -          outbound      EDS
prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                              9090      -          outbound      EDS
prometheus_stats                                                       -         -          -             STATIC
rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local                                    5672      -          outbound      EDS
rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local                                    15672     -          outbound      EDS
sds-grpc                                                               -         -          -             STATIC
tracing.istio-system.svc.cluster.local                                 80        -          outbound      EDS
transaction.prod.svc.cluster.local                                     8084      -          outbound      EDS            transaction.prod
xds-grpc                                                               -         -          -             STATIC
zipkin                                                                 -         -          -             STRICT_DNS
zipkin.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
```

My proxy-config listeners for my api-gateway is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14HCPbNN7ejt1ecwEdrFIH7dHhEdSs716/view?usp=share_link)

Please i need all the help i can get.

Comment: Get a config dump from the gateway pod, as I'm not sure that `'*.local'` in the DR is working fine here. Are you using sidecar injected pods for the apps?

Comment: @ArnauSenserrich i have updated the question and i have added the link to my config dump. And yes all the pods in my prod namespace have sidecar injected. Thanks